# Find string but exclude if it is part of another string

Tags: java, regex

Have the following string:

```
text TOKEN text TOKEN text <elem attr="text TOKEN text">text TOKEN text TOKEN</elem> text TOKEN text
```

Need a RegEx that will give me all TOKEN but NOT in any part of any elem element

EDIT: I do have the RegEx to gather all elem elements.

```
<elem(.*?)>(.*?)</elem>
```

I cannot figure out how to exclude these from the RegEx to find TOKEN

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flavour" but this will be used in Java

Comment: Don't use Regex to handle HTML parsing.

Comment: This is not pure HTML. This is text that happens to include some XML elements. I need a RegEx to exclude these from the search for TOKEN

Comment: You should include more details, maybe actual searched TOKEN. It's not very clear what you ask here.

Comment: @ka: replace TOKEN with any word. Let's say IBM. I need to replace IBM with Microsoft but not if IBM is in any part of an elem element (between <elem and </elem> )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will not match `"TOKEN"` when `"</elem>"` appears before `"<elem"` ahead in the string.

```
"TOKEN(?!(?:(?!<elem).)*</elem>)"
```

If the string may contain newline characters, add the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

Further explanation on request.